# JQuery accordion not displaying in Chrome/IE. Works in Codepen

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

All.

I'm working on a User Guide and started using jQuery accordion. It displays fine in Codepen and seems to have no errors, but when I save it as an HTML and try to display it in Chrome/IE, it's not working. Nothing comes up, just the sections themselves with no collapsing.

This is my code:

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQueryUIAccordion-Defaultfunctionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet"href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script>
        $(function(){
          $(".accordion").accordion();
        });
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="accordion">
      <h2>Content Managers</h2>
         <div class="accordion">
            <h3>Content Manager 1</h3>
            <p>
               Whatever comes in here.
            </p>
            <h3>Content Manager 2</h3>
            <p>
               Whatever comes in here.
            </p>
            <h3>Content Manager 3</h3>
            <p>
               Blah Blah
            </p>
         </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Am I missing something? I saved it an as HTML locally and tried previewing it in Chrome, but it's not displayed (IE11, Chrome  46.0.2490.80 m). Shouldn't it be displayed?

Thanks,
L

Comment: That code works for me.

Comment: In Chrome? Are you just seeing a plain list or do you see the accordion?

Comment: Oh, I think I can see why. I created the page, viewed it using http://... then used file->save to save it to my desktop. Then it opened fine because the save process saves a copy of the js in a folder. But almost certainly the script in your case just isn't being loaded because of the relative references.

Comment: Yes - when I access the page using a file:// url it fails to fetch the js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these lines

```
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The reason for the change is that the urls are trying to access using the file// scheme when you access locally.